# Array reading nightmare

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm sure thats gonna be something I'm missing or something but right now I cant find what Im doing wrong, could you help me find why "Wordmeanings" is not assigning properly the meanings to its correct word? I mean:

- "aquelarre" should be showing "m. Junta o reunión nocturna de brujos y brujas, con la supuesta intervención del demonio ordinariamente en figura de macho cabrío, para sus prácticas mágicas o supersticiosas."
- "diáfano" should be showing "adj. Dicho de un cuerpo: Que deja pasar a su través la luz casi en su totalidad.", "adj. claro (‖ que se percibe bien). Una luz diáfana. Un lenguaje diáfano.", "adj. Dicho de un espacio: Despejado, o que carece de obstáculos o separaciones. Una sala diáfana."
- "epifanía" should be showing "f. Manifestación, aparición o revelación.", "f. Festividad que celebra la Iglesia católica el día 6 de enero, en conmemoración de la adoración de los Reyes Magos."

But I'm afraid is not like that... because as you can see in the pen, each word is showing meanings that are not the desired ones... Sure its somthing Im doing wrong reading the arrays but Can't find the error ¿coul d u help me?

this is the pen: https://codepen.io/stsanchez/pen/WZqwpN?editors=0010#0

```
    $.getJSON( "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/staranco/smarted/master/js/dictionary.json", function(data) {
  var dictionary = data.dictionary;
  var d;
  for(d = 0; d < dictionary.length; d ++) {
    var letters = dictionary[d];
    var letterSectionId = (Object.keys(letters)).toString();
    var letterSection = $('<section/>', {
      'class': 'results__letter',
      'id': 'section_letter-' + letterSectionId
    }).appendTo('.results__container');
    $.each(letters, function(i, item) {
      var words = Object.values(letters[i]);
      var w;
      for(w = 0; w < words.length; w ++) {
        var word = Object.values(words[w])[0];
        var wordName = Object.values(word[0]).toString();
        var wordEtymology = Object.values(word[1]).toString();
        //To do: show word meanings
        var wordMeanings = Object.values(word[2]);
        $.each(wordMeanings, function(j, item) {
          $('<ul/>', {
          'class': 'article__definitions',
          html: ('<li class="article__definition">' + wordMeanings[j] + '</li>')
          }).appendTo('.results__article')
        }); 
        var wordArticle = $('<article/>', {
          'class': 'results__article',
          'data-letter': letterSectionId,
          html: ('<header class="article__header">' + wordName + '</header><p class="article__specs">' + wordEtymology + '</p>')
        }).appendTo('.results__letter#section_letter-' + letterSectionId);
      }
    })}}).done(function() {}).fail(function() {}).always(function() {})
```

and here is the JSON
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/staranco/smarted/master/js/dictionary.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this out. Hope this work as you expected

```
$(function(){
    $.getJSON( "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/staranco/smarted/master/js/dictionary.json", function(data) {
  var dictionary = data.dictionary;
  var d;
  for(d = 0; d < dictionary.length; d ++) {
    var letters = dictionary[d];
    var letterSectionId = (Object.keys(letters)).toString();
    var letterSection = $('<section/>', {
      'class': 'results__letter',
      'id': 'section_letter-' + letterSectionId
    }).appendTo('.results__container');

    $.each(letters, function(i, item) {
      var words = Object.values(letters[i]);
      var w;
      for(w = 0; w < words.length; w ++) {
        var word = Object.values(words[w])[0];
        var wordName = Object.values(word[0]).toString();
        var wordEtymology = Object.values(word[1]).toString();
        //To do: show word meanings
        var wordMeanings = Object.values(word[2]);
        var wordArticle = $('<article/>', {
          'class': 'results__article',
          'data-letter': letterSectionId,
          html: ('<header class="article__header">' + wordName + '</header><p class="article__specs">' + wordEtymology + '</p>')
        }).appendTo('.results__letter#section_letter-' + letterSectionId);
    $.each(wordMeanings, function(j, items) {
        var html='';
        $.each(items, function(k, item){
            html = html + '<li class="article__definition">' + item + '</li>';
        });
      $('<ul/>', {
      'class': 'article__definitions',
      html: (html)
      }).appendTo('.results__letter#section_letter-' + letterSectionId +' .results__article')
    });
      }
    })
  }
}).done(function() {}).fail(function() {}).always(function() {});
});
```

Also observe the changes i have made in your code to understand the mistake.

i have moved the below code after appending the wordArticle. and also changed `.appendTo('.results__article')` to `.appendTo('.results__letter#section_letter-' + letterSectionId +' .results__article')` as only appending to class will append to all the divs with same class.

```
$.each(wordMeanings, function(j, item) {
      $('<ul/>', {
      'class': 'article__definitions',
      html: ('<li class="article__definition">' + wordMeanings[j] + '</li>')
      }).appendTo('.results__letter#section_letter-' + letterSectionId +' .results__article')
    });
```

Comment: I have updated the code for list issue too. Enjoy :)